# Next.js 13 - Why is google analytics and tagmanager automatically in <head>?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-analytics

Can anybody explain me where this tags come from and how could I delete/disable/handle it?
I can't find anything of google in all the code (fresh created next js 13 project).

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={id}=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>

script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id={id}"></script>
```

I'm new to next js and have only googled and searched in the code but sadly I didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Next does not automatically inject Google Tag Manager scripts into your project.

I would expect something else is injecting those tags into your page, possibly a browser extension. To confirm this you can open the page in an incognito window and check if you can still find the tag.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it's curious where it comes from. I don't have installed any browser extension.